# Determine the weak convergence and applicable the weak limit

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$(\mu_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ is the probability measure,  $\lambda$ a Lebesgue-measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \cal{B}\mathbb{(R)})$

$$(\mu_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} = f_n \lambda, f_n(x) = \sqrt{\frac{n}{2 \pi}}e^\frac{-nx^2}{2}$$

I have started to study probability theorem on my own and I have no clue how to solve the exercise above. Sure convergence or pointwise convergence didn't help me I was thinking about Lévy’s continuity theorem also but I'm totally struggling or eventually by computing the distribution function would be useful. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Do you a random variable with density $f_n$? Can you compute its characteristic function?

Answer (score 1):

$\mu_n$ is nothing but  the normal distrbution with mean $0$ and variance $\frac 1 n$. If $X_n $ is distributed as $\mu_n$ the $EX_n^{2}=\frac 1 n$ so $EX_n^{2} \to 0$. This implies that  $X_n \to 0$ in probability and convergence in probability implies weak convergence. So $\mu_n$ converges weakly to the degenerate distribution at $0$.